# In Lwuit, How to handle Keypad navigation Events?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

In the application I'm building I have Tabs and a list in for each Tab. the behavior I want is when I press the Left/Right Nav Key the selected Tab will change. when I press the Up/Down Nav Key the List will change selection index.

I used LWUIT GUI builder to generate `StateMachine/StateMachineBase` class.

I've been trying to fix this all day. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pheromix's answer is correct but he didn't account for the `UIBuilder`. To override the Form creation in the UIBuilder override the method:

```
protected Component createComponentInstance(String componentType, Class cls) {
    if(cls == com.sun.lwuit.Form.class) {
        return new MyFormSubclass();
    }
    return super.createComponentInstance(componentType, cls);
}
```

There is an option to override the Tab selection behavior but to get the most accurate behavior this might be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you complicate your life ? Just use `keyReleased` method implementation in your class. Make a test :

```
if (display.getGameAction(keyCode) == Display.GAME_LEFT || display.getGameAction(keyCode) == Display.GAME_RIGHT)
{
    if (tab.getSelectedIndex == 0)
        tab.setSelectedIndex(1);
    else
        tab.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
else if (display.getGameAction(keyCode) == Display.GAME_UP || display.getGameAction(keyCode) == Display.GAME_DOWN)
{
    if (list.hasFocus())
        super.keyReleased(keyCode);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why either. I tried that but I can't. when I tried to access from the StateMachine class the form is already created. there is no chance for me to override the keyRelease();

Just now I was able to override it. but I'm not sure it's the proper implementation. in beforeMainForm() I added f.addGameKeyListener() the do the selection from there.

Still super Thanx bro!